# Error After Switching to Protected Mode and Making a Far Jump

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, fasm, bochs

I am writing a boot loader using *FASM* (the Flat Assembler). I was successful in 16-bit mode but I am facing an error in switching to 32-bit mode. I looked at an answer to a similar (infact same problem at [GPF after far jump to protected mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983218/gpf-after-far-jump-to-protected-mode)) but the solution doesn't solve my problem.

Here's my boot loader -

```
org 0x7c00

jmp main

include 'bios.asm'
include 'print32.asm'
include 'gdt.asm'

main:

mov bp,0x9000
mov sp,bp

mov bx, bootMsg
call print_string

lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
cli
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 0x1
mov cr0, eax
jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm   ;**The error seems to occurs here

jmp $

bits = 32

init_pm:
    mov ax,DATA_SEG
    mov ds,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov es,ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp
    jmp BEGIN_PM

BEGIN_PM:
    mov ebx, pmMsg
    call print_string32
    jmp $

pmMsg:
    db "Sucessfully switched to the 32-bit protected mode....",0

bootMsg:
    db "Booted in 16-bit Real Mode mode....",0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Here's the GDT -

```
gdt_start:
gdt_null:
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0

gdt_code:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

Hers is th Bochs console output -

```
00478171069i[BIOS  ] Booting from 0000:7c00
00478195765e[CPU0  ] write_virtual_checks(): write beyond limit, r/w
00478195765e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x0d)
00478195765e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x08)
00478195765i[CPU0  ] CPU is in protected mode (active)
00478195765i[CPU0  ] CS.mode = 32 bit
00478195765i[CPU0  ] SS.mode = 32 bit
00478195765i[CPU0  ] EFER   = 0x00000000
00478195765i[CPU0  ] | EAX=d88e0010  EBX=00007d77  ECX=00090000  EDX=00000000
00478195765i[CPU0  ] | ESP=00009000  EBP=00000000  ESI=000e0000  EDI=0000ffac
00478195765i[CPU0  ] | IOPL=0 id vip vif ac vm RF nt of df if tf sf zf af PF cf
00478195765i[CPU0  ] | SEG sltr(index|ti|rpl)     base    limit G D
00478195765i[CPU0  ] |  CS:0008( 0001| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00478195765i[CPU0  ] |  DS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00478195765i[CPU0  ] |  SS:0010( 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00478195765i[CPU0  ] |  ES:0010( 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00478195765i[CPU0  ] |  FS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00478195765i[CPU0  ] |  GS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00478195765i[CPU0  ] | EIP=00007d2f (00007d2f)
00478195765i[CPU0  ] | CR0=0x60000011 CR2=0x00000000
00478195765i[CPU0  ] | CR3=0x00000000 CR4=0x00000000
00478195765i[CPU0  ] 0x0000000000007d2f>> or dword ptr ds:[eax], eax : 0900
00478195765e[CPU0  ] exception(): 3rd (13) exception with no resolution, shutdown status is 00h, resetting
```

Can anyone please help me with this? This has been troubling me since long..

EDIT-

Here's the print32 code-

```
use32

VIDEO_MEM equ 0xb8000
W_O_B equ 0x0f

print_string32:
    pusha
    mov edx,VIDEO_MEM

print_string32_loop:
    mov al, [ebx]
    mov ah, W_O_B
    cmp al,0
    je print_string32_end
    mov [edx],ax
    inc ebx
    add edx,2
    jmp print_string32_loop

print_string32_end:
    popa
    ret
```

And the changed code for the bootloader -

```
org 0x7c00

mov bp,0x9000
mov sp,bp

mov bx, bootMsg
call print_string

cli
lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 0x1
mov cr0, eax
jmp 0x8:init_pm

jmp $

use32

init_pm:
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp,0x90000
    mov esp,0x90000

    jmp BEGIN_PM

jmp $

include 'bios.asm'
include 'gdt.asm'
include 'print32.asm'

use32

BEGIN_PM:
    mov ebx, pmMsg
    call print_string32
    jmp $

pmMsg:
    db "Sucessfully switched to the 32-bit protected mode....",0

bootMsg:
    db "Booted in 16-bit Real Mode mode....",0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: Did you try to use Bochs internal debugger to step through the instructions to find out  which one faults? I might be reading it wrong but it seems that you made it into protected mode and then it failed at an instruction like `dword ptr ds:[eax], eax` at address 0x7d2f.  _EAX_ seems to contain junk and is being used as a pointer, and DS seems to be set to a segment selector of 0 where I would have expected it to be 0x10.

Comment: Not related to your problem but `mov bp,0x9000` `mov sp,bp` is not an appropriate way to set a real mode stack pointer. You should set _SS_ followed by SP. If you want the stack at 0x0000:0x9000 or physical address 0x9000  then do `xor ax, ax` `mov ss, ax` `mov sp, 0x9000`

Comment: I didn't use any debugger but when  jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm isn't there, the system stops without any error but bochs doesn't inform about the switch to protected mode.

Comment: To be quite frank `or dword ptr ds:[eax], eax` seems like a nonesense instruction. Almost suggesting you might have been executing data as instructions

Comment: Using a debugger will be the best thing you can do because you would be able to determine if `jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm` actually succeeded. Without seeing all the code for bios.asm, print32.asm, gdt.asm and your compete bootloader it is hard to say.

Comment: Actually I just noticed something in your code that might be causing issues . You have `bits = 32`  . You should have `bits 32` without the equal sign. Likely your instructions are still being encoded as 16-bit when they should be 32-bit, and when run in protected mode they are being decoded incorrectly. `bits = 32` would have just been setting a constant value called `bits` with the value 32 which is not what you want. Try `bits 32` and let me know what happens.

Comment: The indications are though that you are in protected mode because it does say `CPU is in protected mode (active)` and it says `CS:0008` meaning that the JMP instruction had to have at least successfully executed to properly set CS to CODE_SEG (0x0008). If the jump had failed _CS_ would likely not be set properly.

Comment: I am using flat assembler and when I used bits 32 the compiler gets an error. So I used bits = 32 which compiles well.

Comment: The problem is likely in code you haven't shown. You need to post a complete example which can be used to verify the problem.

Comment: Fine I might not be able to post it now, as I am not using a PC. So I will post the code as soon as possible and let you know. Thanks

Comment: No @RossRidge: I am absolutely positive now that the problem is in the code they are showing, and it is because they aren't setting 32-bit instruction generation properly. And I think what happened was the code after `init_pm` got decoded wrong and the strange `dword ptr ds:[eax], eax` instruction was decoded from parts of these instructions `mov ebp, 0x90000` `mov esp, ebp`

Comment: I have never used _FASM_ the code looked like _NASM_ (your question didn't say). `bits =32` likely didn't set instruction generation to 32-bit as you think it did and is the cause of the issues. If this is _FASM_  you'll need to find the proper way to change to 32-bit instructions

Comment: Should be easy enough to confirm that Michael's idea is correct, using a disassembler (or the BOCHS built-in debugger / disassembler, which you should definitely be using to reduce the amount of trial and error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** : To fix change `bits = 32` to `use32`

To get *FASM* to generate instructions for a processor running in 32-bit mode. The [FASM Documentation](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual) states in *Section 1.1.4 Output Formats* :

> By default, when there is no format directive in source file, flat assembler simply puts generated instruction codes into output, creating this way flat binary file. By **default** it generates **16-bit code**, but you can always turn it into the 16-bit or **32-bit mode** by using use16 or **use32** directive.

It appears you used `bits = 32` when converting *NASM* code to *FASM* and `bits 32` wasn't accepted by *FASM*. `bits=32` sets a constant value named `bits` to the value 32. It doesn't tell *FASM* to generate instructions to be used by a processor in 32-bit mode. Although `bits = 32` assembled without error, it did not do what you expected.

By not using `use32` you told *FASM* to generate code after `init_pm` with instructions that use 32-bit addresses and operands that work in 16-bit real mode, rather than instructions that use 32-bit addresses and operands that work in 32-bit protected mode.

---

Although I can't test your code I'm going to make these observations while I was trying to understand what might have been going on with the code you did post. First of all *BOCHS* dumps these lines:

```
[CPU0  ] 0x0000000000007d2f>> or dword ptr ds:[eax], eax : 0900
[CPU0  ] exception(): 3rd (13) exception with no resolution, shutdown status is 00h, resetting
```

This says that at address 0x7d2f the instruction `or dword ptr ds:[eax], eax` was encountered (its encoding being 0900) and generated exception 13 (General Protection Fault).

There are things in the *BOCHS* state dump at the time that suggest you are in protected mode:

> ```
> CPU is in protected mode (active)
> ```

Additionally there is an indication that `jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm` executed properly. This is suggested by the fact that at the time of your error *BOCHS* dumped `CS:0008` which means that *CS* was set to the value 0008 (= `CODE_SEG`). The *DS* selector is 0 which is unusual given that after the *JMP* you set it to DATA_SEG (0x10) BUT the *ES* and *SS* segment selectors were set to 0x10. This all suggests the `init_pm` code was executed but somehow it ended up not executing as expected.

At this point I realized you had written `bits = 32` which effectively sets a constant to the value 32. It doesn't tell *FASM* to generate code that will be targeting a CPU that will be executing in 32-bit mode.

With this in mind I decided to take the instructions and have the assembler encode them for 16-bit mode:

```
init_pm:
    mov ax,DATA_SEG
    mov ds,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov es,ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
```

When I dumped my test code with *NDISASM* using the `-b32` option (to force *NDISASM* to decode as a 32-bit target), it decoded it to:

```
00000000  B810008ED8        mov eax,0xd88e0010
00000005  8ED0              mov ss,eax
00000007  8EC0              mov es,eax
00000009  66BD0000          mov bp,0x0
0000000D  0900              or [eax],eax
0000000F  6689EC            mov sp,bp
```

The incorrect decoding first did `mov eax, 0xd88e0010`. This explains why in your *BOCHS* dump you have `EAX=d88e0010`  . The lower 16-bits of *EAX* got moved to *ES* so ES=0x0010 which matches your *BOCHS* output `ES:0010` . Similar thing applies to *SS* being set. *BP* was set to 0 which is confirmed in the *BOCHS* output `BP:0000`. This instruction causes the fault and crash:

```
0000000D  0900              or [eax],eax
```

`or [eax],eax` is the same as `or ds:[eax],eax` . `[eax]` has an implicit reference to *DS* . Compare this instruction to the *BOCHS* output:

```
0x0000000000007d2f>> or dword ptr ds:[eax], eax : 0900
```

AHA, that is where this unusual instruction came from (you can ignore the `DWORD PTR`). The incorrectly decoded instruction attempts to use *DS* which point to the NULL (0x0000) descriptor. This causes a processor fault, and the subsequent error reported by *BOCHS* and the state dump.

---

As I stated in the comments, using the internal debugger in *BOCHS* is valuable especially when debugging bootloaders and kernels. If you had stepped through the bootloader instructions one at a time in the debugger you would have probably found that your *FAR JMP* to `init_pm` worked as expected. You would have then observed unexpected instructions being executed that eventually led to a [processor fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thanks !! It works. No error is displayed now. But another problem arose - Bochs now doesn't output any switch to protected mode and the print32 isn't printing anything. Can you help me find out what's the problem? I have edited the code and posted the print32.asm file.

Comment: @AneeshSharma . Your new problem should be a new question, and probably solved by using a debugger, however as to why your print doesn't work I don't see where you actually update video memory. Seems like you might be missing `mov [edx], ax` AFTER `je print_string32_end`.

Comment: That was a silly mistake by me. I added that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it does print that

Comment: @AneeshSharma Now that you have a `use32` did you make sure that your 16-bit code in `bios.asm` has a `use16`?

Comment: Fine I'll do that

Comment: I have added the question. Can you check it please - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608643/printing-text-in-protected-mode-doesnt-work